# How can I Install Java JDK7, apache tomcat , eclipse , spring tool suite in my ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apache2, java, eclipse, jdk, tomcat

could anyone tell me how to install Java JDK7 , apache tomcat , eclipse , spring tool suite in my ubuntu 14.04 ? Provide proper steps .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `sudo apt-get update`

---

JDK7 : `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless` 
 Tomcat7: `sudo apt-get install tomcat7` 
 Eclipse (4.3): `sudo apt-get install eclipse`

---

Spring Tool Suite: 
 `cd /opt` 
`wget  http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.6.3/dist/e4.4/spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz` 
 `sudo tar -xvf <filename>.tar.gz`
  It should create a directory `/opt/sts-bundle/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE` so create a symlink in /`usr/local/bin/sts` 
`ln -s /opt/sts-bundle/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/STS /usr/local/bin/sts` 
 
 to run type `sts` in shell

---

Eclipse (4.4):

- Download Eclipse Luna (4.4) from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux
- Extract and move the package to /opt/
- For a launcher shortcut: create a file /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop and put the following lines in it
  `[Desktop Entry]
  Name=Eclipse 4
  Type=Application
  Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
  Terminal=false
  Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
  Comment=Integrated Development Environment
  NoDisplay=false
  Categories=Development;IDE;
  Name[en]=Eclipse`

Comment: Eclipse is outdated in the repositories

Comment: If **latest** is what you want, why are you trying to install JDK7 and not 8?

Comment: Upvote the answer if the solution has worked or better yet make it the accepted answer so that other people can benefit from it.

Comment: Your answer has two marks for deletion and a score of -1. Why should anyone upvote your answer?

Comment: Why don't you create one more account to mark it to delete again? Don't be so obnoxious, we're all here as a "community". Also, it's just a post not a life and death decision.